# How to measure usability to get hard data?

Tags: usability

There are a few posts on usability but none of them was useful to me.

I need a quantitative measure of usability of some part of an application. 
I need to estimate it in hard numbers to be able to compare it with future versions (for e.g. reporting purposes). The simplest way is to count clicks and keystrokes, but this seems too simple (for example is the cost of filling a text field a simple sum of typing all the letters ? - I guess it is more complicated).
I need some mathematical model for that so I can estimate the numbers.

Does anyone know anything about this?

P.S. I don't need links to resources about designing user interfaces. I already have them. What I need is a mathematical apparatus to measure existing applications interface usability in hard numbers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.techsmith.com/morae.asp

This is what Microsoft used in part when they spent millions redesigning Office 2007 with the ribbon toolbar.

Here is how Office 2007 was analyzed:
http://cs.winona.edu/CSConference/2007proceedings/caty.pdf

Be sure to check out the references at the end of the PDF too, there's a ton of good stuff there. Look up how Microsoft did Office 2007 (regardless of how you feel about it), they spent a ton of money on this stuff.

Comment: Considering how much most people I know hate the Office 2007 ribbon, I'm not sure I'd want to use their methodology as a guideline.

Comment: I think the people who hate it are a lot more vocal than the ones who don't -- and besides, who ever likes change? I'd bet that new users (who learned Office with the ribbon) would hate the old interface more, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your main ideas to approach in this are Effectiveness and Efficiency (and, in some cases, Efficacy).  The basic points to remember are outlined [on this webpage](http://www.usabilitymetrics.com/usability-metrics.html).

What you really want to look at doing is 'inspection' methods of measuring usability.  These are typically more expensive to set up (both in terms of time, and finance), but can yield significant results if done properly.  These methods include things like heuristic evaluation, which is simply comparing the system interface, and the usage of the system interface, with your usability heuristics (though, from what you've said above, this probably isn't what you're after).

More suited to your use, however, will be 'testing' methods, whereby you observe users performing tasks on your system.  This is partially related to the point of effectiveness and efficiency, but can include various things, such as the "Think Aloud" concept (which works really well in certain circumstances, depending on the software being tested).

Jakob Nielsen has a [decent (short) article on his website](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20010121.html).  There's [another one](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/quantitative_testing.html), but it's more related to how to test in order to be representative, rather than how to perform the testing itself.

Answer (score 0):

Consider measuring the time to perform critical tasks (using a new user and an experienced user) and the number of data entry errors for performing those tasks.

Answer (score 0):

First you want to define goals: for example increasing the percentage of users who can complete a certain set of tasks, and reducing the time they need for it.

Then, get two cameras, a few users (5-10) give them a list of tasks to complete and ask them to think out loud. Half of the users should use the "old" system, the rest should use the new one.

Review the tapes, measure the time it took, measure success rates, discuss endlessly about interpretations.

Alternatively, you can develop a system for bucket-testing -- it works the same way, though it makes it far more difficult to find out something new. On the other hand, it's much cheaper, so you can do many more iterations. Of course that's limited to sites you can open to public testing.

That obviously implies you're trying to get comparative data between two designs. I can't think of a way of expressing usability as a value.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the [GOMS model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOMS) (Goals, Operators, Methods, and Selection rules). It is a very difficult research tool to use in my opinion, but it does provide a "mathematical" basis to measure performance in a strictly controlled environment. It is best used with "expert" users. See this very interesting [case study of Project Ernestine](http://www.rpi.edu/~grayw/pubs/papers/1993/GJ&A93_HCIj.pdf) for New England Telephone operators.

Answer (score 0):

Measuring usability quantitatively is an extremely hard problem. I tackled this as a part of my doctoral work. The short answer is, yes, you can measure it; no, you can't use the results in a vacuum. You have to understand *why* something took longer or shorter; simply comparing numbers is worse than useless, because it's misleading.

For comparing alternate interfaces it works okay. In a longitudinal study, where users are bringing their past expertise with version 1 into their use of version 2, it's not going to be as useful. You will also need to take into account time to learn the interface, including time to re-understand the interface if the user's been away from it. Finally, if the task is of variable difficulty (and this is the usual case in the real world) then your numbers will be all over the map unless you have some way to factor out this difficulty.

GOMS (mentioned above) is a good method to use during the design phase to get an intuition about whether interface A is better than B at doing a specific task. However, it only addresses error-free performance by expert users, and only measures low-level task execution time. If the user figures out a more efficient way to do their work that you haven't thought of, you won't have a GOMS estimate for it and will have to draft one up.

Some specific measures that you could look into:

- Measuring clock time for a standard task is good if you want to know what takes a long time. However, lab tests generally involve test subjects working much harder and concentrating much more than they do in everyday work, so comparing results from the lab to real users is going to be misleading.
- Error rate: how often the user makes mistakes or backtracks. Especially if you notice the same sort of error occurring over and over again.
- Appearance of workarounds; if your users are working around a feature, or taking a bunch of steps that you think are dumb, it may be a sign that your interface doesn't give the tools to figure out how to solve their problems.
- Don't underestimate simply asking users how well they thought things went. Subjective usability is finicky but can be revealing.