# Measure the user experience of a website

Tags: user-experience

I know that this is no technical question, but since someone has posted a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619052/how-to-measure-usability-to-get-hard-data) I thought it should be ok.
What I want to do is to measure the user experience of any website. Ideally, I would like to use some type of algorithm to get a number with a corresponding metric to evaluate the user experience.
I can think of some type of heuristics, e.g. if user gets a 404-error, the user experience is very low. On the other hand, if he or she buys something in an online store, the user experience is high. Of course this would not work if the page is e.g. a news page.

Does anyone of you know how I could calculate the user experience for websites?

Thanks in advance,

enne

Comment: What is your goal in measuring the user experience via algorithm?

Comment: Well, I want to create a program that a user has to install and that injects a small javascript in the client-side html code. Furthermore, this javascript should collect data concerning what the user does on the website and send this data back to the server. There, the collected values should be evaluated.

Comment: This tells me the mechanism that you want to use, but not your actual goal in measuring the user experience via algorithm.  You get somewhat close to it with "the collected values should be evaluated", but you haven't yet identified what the goal is in collecting and evaluating the data.

Comment: What I want to know is if the user is satisfied or not concerning the websites he's visited. Let's say I calculate a number between 0 and ten, where 0 is completely unsatisfied and 10 means he/she is satisfied. All between would be tolerated.

Comment: What you've described in this comment isn't your question.  The question is looking for either things that the user has done (purchased something) or experienced (error), whereas this says that you want interaction from the user.

You can gather metrics, which will tell you that something happened, but you won't know what the user thinks about it unless you actually ask them.  You're better off conducting user research to understand what a good user experience is, instead of trying to guess which metrics might be associated with a good (or bad) experience.

Comment: Thanks nadyne for your hint. One question: Do you know any good data sources where I can find out more about user's intentions (questionnaires, surveys, etc.)?

Comment: This is the point where you should engage with a user experience professional.  Your goal is an excellent one.  Just as you wouldn't throw a database expert at OS kernel code, being able to design a good user experience and analyze data about user experience is something that is most efficiently done by an expert in the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand from your question is that you want to measure the user experience based on technical terms, i.e.: number of views for a specific page, number of error pages showed to users, how many times a link has been clicked, what locations the users come from all over the world, and so on.

So, I think you are asking about website analytics, which you custom to do measurements for whatever you want, as famous examples for those tools:

- [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/)
- [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)
- [Open Web Analytics](http://www.openwebanalytics.com/) (open source)

Please let me know if I answered your question.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the interesting tools, I'll have a look at them!

Comment: The wording of the question does indeed suggest an answer that involves measurement of business outcomes -- page views, time on page, completion rates etc. But they are not measurements of user experience. For that, you really need to talk to (or at least observe) some users.

Comment: That's true, indeed. I think a survey could be helpful.